# Assignen a template function with Variadic arguments to a function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

In C++ I am trying to make forwarding wrapper that takes the first argument and calls a method on it.
This ended up in the `wrapper` method in the given code. This works fine when calling it.

However I want to assign this templated wrapper to function pointer. In my use-case the function pointer is a given and I can not change it to a `std::function` or something like that. This is because the place where it is used in a C api.

I did create the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<auto FUNC, typename T, typename ... Params>
static auto wrapper(void* handle, Params&& ... args) {
    auto* ser = static_cast<T*>(handle);
    return (ser->*FUNC)(std::forward<Params>(args)...);
}

class MyTestClass {
public:
    int method1(int i, int j) { return i + j; }

    float method2(float f) {
        return f * 2;
    }
};

int main() {
    MyTestClass thing{};

    int (*serialize)(void* handle, int i, int j);

    serialize = wrapper<&MyTestClass::method1, MyTestClass>;
    
    auto callMethod1Result = wrapper<&MyTestClass::method1, MyTestClass>(&thing, 1, 2);
    std::cout << "callMethod1Result: " << callMethod1Result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The calling of the method works fine, however:

```cpp
    int (*serialize)(void* handle, int i, int j);
    serialize = wrapper<&MyTestClass::method1, MyTestClass>;
```

does not work, giving me the error:

```
/.../temp.cpp:23:17: error: no matches converting function ‘wrapper’ to type ‘int (*)(void*, int, int)’
     serialize = wrapper<&MyTestClass::method1, MyTestClass>;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/.../temp.cpp:4:13: note: candidate is: ‘template<auto FUNC, class T, class ... Params> auto wrapper(void*, Params&& ...)’
 static auto wrapper(void* handle, Params&& ... args) {
             ^~~~~~~
```

after some trying I did find out that the `Params&& ... args` part is causing the issue, because if I make a more explicit wrapper without variadic argument, then it does work.

My main question is: Can I assign a templated method with variadic argument to a function pointer, and how?

Comment: There are no "template functions" in C++, there are function templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `wrapper` taking `args` as forwarding reference, its type would always be reference: lvalue-reference or rvalue-reference. But `serialize` is declared as function pointer taking `i` and `j` by-value with type `int`, they can't match reference type, which makes template argument deduction on `Params` fails in `serialize = wrapper<&MyTestClass::method1, MyTestClass>;`.

You can fix it by changing type of `i` and `j` in declaration of `serialize`.

E.g.

```
int (*serialize)(void* handle, int&& i, int&& j);
serialize = wrapper<&MyTestClass::method1, MyTestClass>;
```

[LIVE Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yv58naTX3NAVV8FA) [LIVE Gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2tMB1YNrPUQHqUlF)

Or change `wrapper` taking `args` by-value.

E.g.

```
template<auto FUNC, typename T, typename ... Params>
static auto wrapper(void* handle, Params ... args)
```

[LIVE Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OMG8ZflEYNtN0pnB) [LIVE Gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pwgrxZgtS9lCcWtC)

Comment: OP stated that `serialize` is used to interact with C API.

Comment: i dont think it's right answer still this code will fail on g++, another thing that i think && is not an problem due to reference collapse.

Comment: @N0ll_Boy Which one doesn't compile with g++? After reference collapse the type would be `int&` or `int&&`, they don't match `int`.

Comment: @songyuanyao should it be `const int &` instead of `int &&` ??

Comment: In my case removing the `&&` from parameter in the `wrapper` method solved my issue.